# Calling 'ls' with root on Android returns nothing, application hangs

Tags: java, android, root

I have an Android application that I'm working on that requires root. It uses root to access some of the internal memory stuff, and then I call `ls` on a directory. I then read from it which works great if there is data, but if the directory is empty, the application just hangs. Is there a good way around this?

Here's the code

```java
    final Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            try {
                // Perform su to get root privileges
                Process p = runtime.exec("su");
                DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
                output.writeBytes("ls " + directoryPath + "\n");
                output.flush();
                InputStream stdout = p.getInputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int read;
                String out = new String();
                while(true){
                    //If ls found no files it hangs on this line
                    read = stdout.read(buffer);
                    out += new String(buffer, 0, read);
                    if(read < 1024){
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me:
see my [process helper](https://bitbucket.org/jholetzeck/ministatus-android/src/0d594b5dbe0f9c838c4a61cb0e339f1ae11cb883/src/de/holetzeck/util/ProcessHelper.java?at=default) and then for example

```
Pair<Integer, String> ret = ProcessHelper.runCmd(true, "su", "-c", "ls -l");
```

Comment: I'm going to try this out later tonight, is it cool if I use your ProcessHelper class?

Comment: I finally got around to implementing that, it works great thank you!